# Custom icons in ribbon bar is not correct rendered

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer

i have the following issue. I have a custom icon for my custom button in the ribbon bar implemented, but this icon can not be rendered correctly. This icons is displayed as . And I don't know how to solve this problem. 
My VisualStudio 2013 solution tree looks like this:
[image: VisualStudio 2013 solution structure]

And my Elements.xml:
[image: Part of the Elements.xml]

I also tried `_layouts/Images/CustomRibbonProject/Symbo_16x16.png`, but neither works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to map your Images folder with {SharePointRoot}\Template\Images and put a `/` before `_layouts` ?

```
    /_layouts/15/Images/CustomRibbonProject/Symbo_16x16.png
```

Good luck

Comment: My Images are mapped with {SharePointRoot}\Template\Images and I put a / before _layouts, but it did not worked...